# Wrap TextFlow inside of VBox

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have a `TextFlow` object inside of a `VBox` (which is the content of a `ScrollPane`), and I need to wrap it if it goes over the VBox (pref) width.
I tried setting the max width of the flow:

```
flow.maxWidthProperty().bind(vbox.prefWidthProperty());
```

But it doesn't wrap. How can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Do you have a ScrollPane inside a VBox or vice-versa. TextFlow itself doesn't have a wrap property, so what do you mean by "wrap a TextFlow"?

Comment: Post a [MCVE]. If the `VBox` is inside a `ScrollPane`, the `VBox` is going to grow as large as it wants to grow, and so the `TextFlow` will too. It's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. The TextFlow, composed by Label(s), is inside of a VBox, that is the content of a ScrollPane. I'd need to go on new line if the flow reaches the VBox width. @James_D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default a scroll pane will allow its content to grow to its preferred size, allowing the user to scroll if it becomes larger than the allocated space. In your case, the preferred width of the `VBox` that is the content of the scroll pane is computed as the preferred width of its child nodes; which of course is the preferred width of the text flow. In turn, the preferred width of the text flow is computed as the width required to show its text *without wrapping*.

It sounds as though what you are trying to do is to restrict the `VBox` so that it cannot grow wider than the scroll pane containing it. You can do this by calling `setFitToWidth(true);` on the scroll pane. This causes the content of the scroll pane to be resized so that its width is equal to the width of the scroll pane's viewport, as long as that is within the range of the content's `minWidth` - `maxWidth`.

Here is a SSCCE:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.scene.text.TextFlow;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TextFlowInScrollPane extends Application {


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextFlow flow = new TextFlow(new Text(text));
        VBox vbox = new VBox(flow);
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(vbox);

        // removing this line will allow the scroll pane to grow
        // to an unlimited width, and so will prevent the text from
        // wrapping:
        scrollPane.setFitToWidth(true);

        Scene scene = new Scene(scrollPane, 400, 400);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private final String text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. "
            + "Duis malesuada nisi non est varius convallis. Donec eu aliquam tellus. "
            + "Duis nulla nulla, mattis non dictum non, bibendum vel eros. "
            + "Cras auctor metus eros, quis porta nisi mattis at. "
            + "Aenean bibendum, elit nec suscipit imperdiet, lorem mauris cursus felis, "
            + "sed suscipit quam nibh faucibus dui. Ut vel condimentum enim. "
            + "Curabitur non lacinia nunc. Quisque ut arcu turpis. Maecenas enim risus, "
            + "cursus eget auctor at, volutpat condimentum ligula. "
            + "Aliquam rutrum consectetur sapien, non imperdiet nisi auctor quis. "
            + "In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla eget lacus ac quam dignissim varius. "
            + "In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin quis pellentesque eros, nec semper nibh."
            + "Integer venenatis aliquam risus volutpat tempor. Aliquam erat volutpat. "
            + "Proin at viverra turpis. Sed luctus purus tortor, ut molestie libero tempus quis. "
            + "Nulla eu viverra nulla. Vivamus ut bibendum lectus, eu lobortis tellus. "
            + "Aliquam pellentesque ipsum ipsum. Sed vel pellentesque sapien, ut egestas arcu. "
            + "Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. "
            + "Curabitur sodales felis at justo congue pharetra. "
            + "Curabitur sodales, urna a pulvinar consectetur, urna dolor rhoncus turpis, vel dapibus neque nisl a leo. "
            + "Maecenas feugiat consequat tortor fermentum molestie. Donec a est et risus porttitor ornare. "
            + "Cras auctor metus sed maximus fringilla. Donec blandit augue eu orci elementum malesuada. "
            + "Aliquam volutpat, enim at lacinia sollicitudin, nibh nisi dignissim erat, "
            + "sit amet accumsan orci lorem vitae nibh."
            + "Maecenas interdum finibus laoreet. Mauris iaculis nibh nec dui lacinia, ut lacinia est venenatis. "
            + "Donec vitae varius eros. Phasellus scelerisque eu risus ac bibendum. "
            + "Morbi luctus, diam ut vehicula tristique, lacus mi ornare lacus, nec hendrerit nulla metus vitae mauris. "
            + "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas mattis luctus nisl non volutpat. "
            + "Aenean euismod tristique libero sit amet dictum. Nulla facilisi. Aenean posuere dapibus convallis."
            + "In vulputate mi quam, ut mattis felis iaculis sed. Phasellus eleifend nunc ex, "
            + "vel commodo diam dictum at. Quisque posuere arcu ut lectus bibendum, non dapibus turpis luctus. "
            + "Nullam quis arcu elit. In convallis rutrum nulla nec feugiat. Curabitur dapibus accumsan quam, "
            + "ut faucibus orci posuere rhoncus. Integer vestibulum ex vitae sem elementum, a laoreet odio porta. "
            + "Suspendisse malesuada cursus euismod. Duis a arcu erat. Integer eu nisi quis lectus convallis suscipit."
            + "Pellentesque iaculis leo at dolor accumsan, nec fermentum urna maximus. "
            + "Aenean ornare congue nisi, nec placerat ipsum. Morbi et pharetra turpis, vel accumsan lorem. "
            + "Aenean tempus maximus velit, sed rutrum purus condimentum nec. Nunc sed aliquet turpis, ac aliquam justo. "
            + "Curabitur lectus urna, facilisis ac sapien vel, lacinia pulvinar mauris. "
            + "Cras venenatis, sapien maximus tincidunt luctus, lectus est auctor leo, id facilisis dui ex a ipsum. "
            + "Duis a urna sed purus semper maximus accumsan non mi. "
            + "Phasellus pharetra tempus sapien, in congue nisi ornare sed. "
            + "Sed mollis, velit eu eleifend elementum, nisi lacus venenatis erat, "
            + "pellentesque pulvinar augue diam eu ex. Maecenas non lacus mauris."
            + "Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. "
            + "Nam maximus eros urna. Vestibulum tempus condimentum nunc sit amet laoreet.";


}
```

[image]

Comment: It still doesn't wrap, it's just "clipped" when it reaches the end of the pane. I add the flows using `vbox.getChildren().add(flow);`

Comment: @GioG. No it doesn't. Look at the screenshot. Did you run my example?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "wrap". The problem is that the flows are created later, not at the start

Comment: @GioG. Please have the basic respect to look at my answer and run the code I provided for free. It clearly wraps at the boundary of the scroll pane, exactly as you asked.

Comment: I'm sorry, man. Anyway, I run the code and I noticed that it works if the TextFlow is composed by Texts, but I need Labels (I have to set the text fill)

Comment: @GioG. Why do you need `Label`s? All the text fill does in a label is set the color of the text, which you can do with `setFill(...)` on a `Text`. If you could have been bothered to post an example (as I asked you yesterday), then I would have pointed this out. Using `Text`s with different colors is even an example in the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html).

Answer (score -2):

The below should wrap the text to the next line.

```
TextFlow tf = new TextFlow();
tf.setStyle("-fx-wrap-text: true");
```

Comment: `TextFlow` is not a `Labeled` and thus doesn't know about `-fx-wrap-text`. If it did, it woukd be netter to use `tf.setWrapText(true)` as it is always better to avoid `.setStyle()` when there is an alternative.